Eine weitere Frage über „prägen"
Ich wollte den Unterschied zwischen „prägen" und „einprägen" (besser) verstehen und habe diesen Eintrag hier gefunden.  In diesem gibt es folgendes Beispiel

Die Stadt wurde den Habsburgern geprägt.

Hier fehlt nicht das „von"?

Die Stadt wurde von den Habsburgern geprägt.

Wenn nicht, was geht hier vor, d.h., wie kann man den Dativ in dieser Passivstruktur
benutzen ohne „von"?

Grammatikalisch ist der Satz auch richtig, aber semantisch gesehen hat du recht

Danke -- kannst du mir erklären, wie es grammatikalisch richtig ist.  Dass heißt, darf man einfach „von" weglassen?  Wie z.B. „Das Buch wurde dem Kind zur Schule getragen"?  Oder verstehe ich nicht das, was du sagst?

@Cerulean Da so ziemlich jedes deutsche Verb mit Dativobjekt verwendet werden kann, kann das von oft weggelassen werden, ohne dass der Satz ungrammatisch wird. Er wird dadurch allerdings in der Regel sinnlos. Prägen mit Dativobjekt könnte in dem folgenden Satz Sinn ergeben: "Prägt mir die Münzen ordentlich!"

First off: as the author of the quoted answer I have to apologize - the left out "von" was simply a typo and wouldn't you have asked I'd not have noticed it. I corrected it now.
To your question:
You cannot leave out the "von" without the sentence changing meaning. You can do it (at least sometimes), but then the whole construct will be a different one and the meaning will be different too.
What it becomes is an example of a general "phrase" in German:

<verb> + <personal pronoun in Dativ>

which means "do the named action for (or on behalf of) the one named in the personal pronoun". Here is an example:

Ich trage das Paket. (I carry the package.)
Ich trage dir das Paket. (I carry the package for you.)

Here is another example with a similar meaning. I guess one could translate "for you" too here:

Ich fülle das Formular aus. (I fill out the form.)
Ich fülle ihm das Formular aus. (I fill out the form on his behalf.)

What you see in action here is the original function of the Dativ: to name the recipient/beneficiary/victim of an action.
So, the sentence in the form quoted by you would mean the city was imprinted to the Habsburgers or for the Habsburgers but not by the Habsburgers as was the intended meaning.
